# 'Implicit' JOIN based on schema's foreign keys?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g

Hello  all :) I'm wondering if there is way to tell the database to look at the schema and infer the JOIN predicate:

```
+--------------+     +---------------+
| prices       |     | products      |
+--------------+     +---------------+
| price_id (PK)|  |-1| product_id(PK)|
| prod_id      |*-|  | weight        |
| shop         |     +---------------+
| unit_price   |
| qty          |
+--------------+
```

Is there a way (preferably in Oracle 10g) to go from:

```
SELECT * FROM prices JOIN product ON prices.prod_id = products.product_id
```

to:

`SELECT * FROM prices`*`IMPLICIT JOIN`*`product`

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Which is good because it would not be very maintainable either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get to not writing the actual join condition is a natural join.

```
select * from t1 natural join t2
```

Oracle will look for columns with identical names and join by them (this is not true in your case). See the [documentation on the SELECT statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702):

> A natural join is based on all columns in the two tables that have the same name. It selects rows from the two tables that have equal values in the relevant columns. If two columns with the same name do not have compatible data types, then an error is raised

**This is very poor practice and I strongly recommend not using it on any environment**

Answer (score 2):

You shouldnt do that. Some db systems allow you to but what if you modify the fk's (i.e. add foreign keys)? You should always state what to join on to avoid problems. Most db systems won't even allow you to do an implicit join though (good!).